# Android SQLiteDatabase insert() method throws Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, android, sqlite, nullpointerexception

I have written a method which allows you to add a "word" to a database. It throws a Null pointer exception when it attempts database.insert() once I call the addWord() method.

```
public class DatabaseControl {

// columns for table
public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_SYNID = "synsetID";
public static final String KEY_WORD = "synsetID";
public static final String KEY_DESCRIPTION = "description";
public static final String KEY_POPULARITY = "popularity";

// table name
public static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "wordnet"; // Name of the Database

private Context context;
private SQLiteDatabase database;
private DatabaseHelper dbHelper;

public DatabaseControl(Context context){
    this.context = context;
}

public DatabaseControl open() throws SQLiteException {
    dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close(){
    dbHelper.close();
}

public long addWord (String synId, String word, String description, int popularity) {
    ContentValues setUpVals = createContentValues(synId, word, description, popularity);
    // SEEMS TO THROW NULL POINTER EXCEPTION
    return database.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null , setUpVals); 
}
```

I call this method here:

```
private void populateDatabase(){
    try {
         long rowId = 0;
         rowId = dbControl.addWord("testSyn","","",1); // Add a row to the database for test
    } 
    catch (SQLiteException e){
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Don't really understand why it's throwing this error, and I don't fully understand the second paramater within insert() so it could be that for all I know :/

Comment: Can you please post the full stack trace?

Comment: do you ever call `open()` ?

Comment: Ahh, it would probably help if I did call open() afterall :/

Answer (score 0):

Try out this way:

```
private void populateDatabase()
{    
    try {
        long rowId = 0;         
        rowId = dbControl.addWord("testSyn",null,null,1); 
    } 
    catch (SQLiteException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```